# Status code 403 forbidden unable to encode multipartform data using postAsync method on wsdl webservice?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, wsdl, abbyy

I am new in `wsdl` webservice I am working on abbyy flexicapture webservice to upload file in fexicapture and get data in xml. Now main problem arises I will get data while my code is in debug mode i.e. on local machine but while I publish my code to remote server I will get 403 error while encoding data at postAsync method. Abbyy flexicapture share one demo project https://help.abbyy.com/en-us/flexicapture/12/developer/unattendedexample by using that code I created one MVC application in which I successfully get data from flexicapture which is on server using window Authentication on my local machine.

I am sharing my error with you please find

```
Error :-EXCEPTION OCCURRED:System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).    at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at WebServices.Controllers.HomeController.<FileRequest>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at WebServices.Controllers.HomeController.<UploadFile>d__17.MoveNext() System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
```

Flexicapture and Webservice are on same IIS which is on remote server.

Thanks in advance please help me on this.

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FileRequest(FlexicaptureWebservice.FlexiCaptureWebServiceSoapClient service, string action,int objectType, int sessionId, int projectId, int batchId, int parentId, int objectId, int version, string streamName)
{

  var creds = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName))
     creds = new NetworkCredential(service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName, service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password);
     using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = creds })
     {                   
       using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
       {
         var uri = service.Endpoint.Address.Uri;
         var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
          {
            {"Action", action},
            {"objectType", objectType.ToString()},
            {"sessionId", sessionId.ToString()},
            {"projectId", projectId.ToString()},
            {"batchId", batchId.ToString()},
            {"parentId", parentId.ToString()},
            {"objectId", objectId.ToString()},
            {"version", version.ToString()},
            {"streamName", streamName},
           });

           var response = await client.PostAsync(uri.OriginalString.Replace("/API/v1/Soap","/FileService/v1").Trim(), content).ConfigureAwait(false);
           response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
           client.Dispose();
           return response;
        }
     }              
  }
```

Comment: can you put a quickwatch on content or log what the encoded content looks like and try sending it via postman? The endpoint might not support tuples which you are sending.  Also can you try setting application/x-www-form-urlencoded as the contenttype.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture first request on working machine.  Then repeat on non working machine and compare.  Check to see if the http headers are the same.  You can use the sniffer on any machine in the subnet so you do not need to run sniffer from server.  On a IIS server the user has limited access to local drive.  Any files needed should be placed on network drive where users have full access.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time As i check content type of debug and publish file both are same also check data send by postman I will not get any error and from @jdweng ans when I check by fiddler and wireshark my VPN stopped and I cannot even authenticate. So I think there is issue on IIS for publish code so could you please tell me which settings should i follow? I enable windows and anonymous authentication in IIS.

Comment: how can we print multipartdata in text file so we can compare local and server file data?

Comment: Does sniffer show http or https (secure).  It secure there is a TLS section using TCP to go secure.  When looking at the TCP make sure you do not see [FIN] indicating the connection closed.  Also check if you are using http 1.0 (stream mode) or http 1.1 (chunk mode).  In chunk mode you have to respond with a NEXT CHUNK otherwise you get a timeout.

Comment: @jdweng my sniffer shows http and sharing my error message StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Persistent-Auth: true Connection: close Date: Tue, 27 Aug 2019 11:51:57 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 42 }

Comment: for unsuccessful request and for successful it gives StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Persistent-Auth: true Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2019 06:27:45 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 1 Content-Type: text/plain Expires: Wed, 28 Aug 2019 10:27:45 GMT } Also, could you please explain me   this line " In chunk mode you have to respond with a NEXT CHUNK otherwise you get a timeout." please give me some refrence on that thanks.

Comment: There doesn't look like there is any error in the headers.  Is there any BODY data?  You may just be getting a query with no data   The exception 403 indicates the response was 403 instead of 200.  So the error may be occurring later in in the sniffer data.  There is a 100 response which is a continue in 1.0.  Paragraph 3.6 of http 1.1 explains chunked : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.6

Comment: @jdweng yes I am passing MultipartFormDataContent in body using Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(streamName) as file byte after uploading that file I used second method which encode that file to original one using FormUrlEncodedContent which I share above so there is no problem while uploading files in multi-part I am facing issue while encoding that file.

Comment: I think the issue would still occur with an empty body.  You have to compare the headers in the first request from the working "MVC application" with the headers in the first request of the non working c# application using a sniffer.  Getting the response message only shows that a failure occurs and not what is causing the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I caused this error because of some authentication problem on server IIS. So on my local build it works fine but while I publish thing on IIS caused error

**I publish my code to remote server I will get 403 error while encoding data at postAsync method.**

> So To remove error I go to->application pool of IIS ->Advance
>   setting->Identity->Add custom account where I put my server
>   credentials that's it.

Now I am able to send files on flexicapture. 
I hope this little change help some developer.